# Lusin's theorem of $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ be a Lebesgue measurable($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure), complex-valued function on the compact interval $[a,b]$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a measurable subset $E\subset [a,b]$ with $\lambda([a,b]\setminus E)<\epsilon$ such that $f\mid_E$ is continuous.

This is the Lusin's theorem in $\mathbb{C}$. I have some questions about the proof of this theorem.

(1)Lusin's theorem does not say that $f$ is continuous at every point of $E$. Is there any counterexample to this incorrect version of Lusin's theorem?

(2)Is its proof different from the proof of the $\mathbb{R}$-version which $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About (1): Take any function which is not continuous at any point, say the function $f(x)=0$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=1$ for $x$ irrational. Then we cannot find any non-empty set $E$ such that $f$ is continuous at all points of $E$.

About (2): Yes, the proof for the complex case is similar to the one for the real case.

Comment: But if I let $E=\mathbb{R}-\cup_{i}I_i$ is the set of all irrational numbers with $I_i$ is the open set of all rational numbers. Isn't it continuous at all points of $E$?

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at any point. The question is not about continuity of the restriction of $f$ to $E$ w.r.t. the relative topology.. It is about continuity at points of $E$ as  a function from $\mathbb R$ into itself.

Comment: So the incorrect version of Lusin's theorem is ask to prove $f$ is continuous at all points? The characteristic function is not continuous at every point. But is it related to the  incorrect version of Lusin's theorem?

Comment: The statements 'the restriction of $f$ to $E$ is continuous' and '$f$ is continuous at all points of $E$' are very different and that is the distinction between the correct version and the incorrect version.

Comment: So it means $f$ is continuous with the restriction which removes the discontinuous point such that $f\mid_E$ be continuous. But $f$ is not continuous on the set $E$.